# ZeroDivisionError when finding average

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, k-means

I've been trying to write my own k-mean algorithm for the past couple of days, but I have hit a roadblock. When ever I try to find the average location of the points in a cluster to move the centroid, I get a zero division error(Note: this doesn't happen when k = 2, and only happens sometimes when k = 3, but always happens when k >= 4). I tried to fix this by making sure each centroid starts off at one of the points in the dataset, so that it always has at least one point in its cluster, but it hasn't worked. I've also rearranged counters and such, but again, it did not work. I have run out of ideas and am not sure why this error still happens. I'm  pretty sure the problem is coming from one of these functions(edit: added all of code and full error message):

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Kmeans:
    def __init__(self, K, dataset, centroids, sorting):
        self.K = K
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.centroids = centroids
        self.sorting = sorting

    def initializeCentroids(self):
        usedPoints = [random.choice(data_set)]
        self.centroids = []
        for q in range(self.K):
            pointSelected = False
            while not pointSelected:
                m = random.choice(data_set)
                print(m)
                print(usedPoints)
                distance = math.sqrt(abs(((m[0] - usedPoints[len(usedPoints) - 1][0]) ** 2) + (m[1] - usedPoints[len(usedPoints) - 1][1]) ** 2))
                if usedPoints.count(m) == 0 and distance > 50:
                    self.centroids.append(list(m))
                    usedPoints.append(m)
                    pointSelected = True
        return self.centroids

    def calcDistance(self):
        self.sorting = []
        for w in self.dataset:
            distances = []
            counter = -1
            for centr in self.centroids:
                counter += 1
                distances.append(math.sqrt(abs((((w[0] - centr[0]) ** 2) + (w[1] - centr[1]) ** 2))))
                for x in range(len(distances)):
                    if len(distances) > 1:
                        print(distances)
                        if distances[0] > distances[1]:
                            distances.pop(0)
                        else:
                            distances.pop(1)
                            counter -= 1
            print(counter)
            self.sorting.insert(0, [w, counter, distances[0]])
        return self.sorting
    # not done

    def find_ME(self):
        counter2 = 0
        for r in self.centroids:
            for t in self.sorting:
                nums = []
                if t[1] == counter2:
                    nums.append(t[2])
                    population = len(nums)
                    error = sum(nums) / population

    def reassignCentroids(self):
        counter3 = 0
        for r in self.centroids:

            positionsX = []
            positionsY = []
            for t in self.sorting:
                if t[1] == counter3:
                    positionsX.append(t[0][0])
                    positionsY.append(t[0][1])
            population = len(positionsY)
            print(population)
            print(self.sorting)
            r[0] = sum(positionsX) / population
            r[1] = sum(positionsY) / population
            counter3 += 1
        return self.centroids

    def checkSimilar(self, prevList):
        list1 = []
        list2 = []
        for u in prevList:
            list1.append(u[1])
        for i in self.sorting:
            list2.append(i[1])
            print(i)
        if list2 == list1:

            return True
        else:
            return False


k = 3
data_set = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (50, 52), (48, 50), (47, 60), (112, 90), (120, 100), (108, 130), (102, 121), (43, 51), (0, 1)]
attempt = Kmeans(k, data_set, [], [])

attempt.initializeCentroids()

xvals = []
yvals = []
sortCompare = []
maxIterations = 100000
# plots

for p in data_set:
    xvals.append(p[0])
    yvals.append(p[1])


running = True
zeroError = True

while running:
    attempt.calcDistance()
    sortCompare = attempt.sorting
    print(sortCompare, "thisss")
    attempt.reassignCentroids()
    attempt.calcDistance()
    attempt.reassignCentroids()
    boolVal = attempt.checkSimilar(sortCompare)
    if boolVal or maxIterations <= 0:
        xs = []
        ys = []
        for y in attempt.centroids:
            xs.append(y[0])
            ys.append(y[1])
        plt.scatter(xs, ys)
        running = False
    else:
        sortCompare = []

    maxIterations -= 1
    print(attempt.sorting)
print(attempt.centroids)
plt.scatter(xvals, yvals)
plt.show()
```

Full error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Jack Cramer/PycharmProjects/kmeans/main.py", line 117, in 
attempt.reassignCentroids()
File "C:/Users/Jack Cramer/PycharmProjects/kmeans/main.py", line 73, in reassignCentroids
r[0] = sum(positionsX) / population
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

If you know why this is happening please let me know, thanks for any advice.

Comment: Could you give the full code (i.e. the class wrapping this code, and some driver code to reproduce the zero division error)?

Comment: You should include the complete error traceback and provide a [mre]

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark added all of the code, thanks for the help

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I added the full error message and the rest of the code

Comment: As the message says, `population` is 0 at this point. Check your data.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, I know population is zero, but I dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thierry-lathuille pointed out, the error occurs in `reassignCentroids` when you divide by `population` which is zero.  `population` is set to be the length of `positionsY`, so we need to see which scenarios cause `positionsY` to have no elements.

`positionsY` has its values appended inside a loop over the values `t in self.sorting`.  A value is only appended if `counter3` (which ranges from 0 to K-1) matches `t[1]`.  So if there is a value of `counter3` for which none of the `t[1]` values are equal, we'll get the error.  To help debug, I've added some print statements to the loop

```
            print(f"{counter3=}")
            for t in self.sorting:
                print(f"{t[1]=}")
                if t[1] == counter3:
                    positionsX.append(t[0][0])
                    positionsY.append(t[0][1])
```

Running this several times with `k=2`, I see that `t[1]` is either 0 or 1, which won't crash, as you see.  However, going up to `k=3`, sometimes I get `t[1]` equal to 0, 1, or 2, but other times it only equals 0 or 1.  This means there will be no matches, and you'll divide by zero.  Going up to `k=4`, we should get `t[1]` equal to 0, 1, 2, or 3, but I'm not seeing any 3's after many restarts.

From context, I'm guessing that `t[1]` represents the cluster that a given data point is closest to.  From your inputs, it appears by eye that there are three clusters of points
[image: scatter plot of data points used in example]
So your code naturally has three of the predicted clusters trend towards the places they should be, so if you're trying to predict 4 clusters, you'll always crash.  If you're only trying to predict 3 clusters, you might get unlucky and one of your predicted clusters isn't the closest to any point.  It wouldn't surprise me if even `k=2` errored out for certain initializations, but it must be rare in practice.

I think you need to first ask yourself what behavior you want to see when `k` is higher than the real number of clusters.  And second you need to determine how to update a cluster's location when none of the data points are closest to it.  A quick workaround would be to do nothing if `population == 0`, though that may not give the behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, added some more data points to make a 4th kind of cluster and it worked after a couple of runs.

Comment: Glad that fixed it!  Still, remember that with real life data, there could be any number of clusters, so you need to make sure your code can handle it.  I'm guessing if you set `k=5` your code will still divide by zero.

Comment: Yeah, I did a bit more research and I think I am going to try and implement a modified version of the algorithm, Macqueens K-means, where for each point reassigned each centroid is also updated, hopefully it will fix it. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Glad you've found a way forward.  It's still not a bad idea to toy around with your own approach for a while before looking up the standard algorithms.  You'll learn a lot that way.